# PHP crawler for one special HTML element

Tags: php, html

We have this simple HTML page (for test!) :

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="my"> One </div>
<div class="my"> Two </div>
<div class="my"> Three </div>
<div class="other"> NO </div>
<div class="other2"> NO </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, i need a very simple php code to crawl.
The thing i want to be crawled, is that i want to have : "one","two","three" into a php array.I need to crawl everything that is into "my" class. And i don't want to have the other classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this you can use `xpath` to get your result

```
$html = '<html>
            <body>
            <div class="my"> One </div>
            <div class="my"> Two </div>
            <div class="my"> Three </div>
            <div class="other"> NO </div>
            <div class="other2"> NO </div>
            </body>
        </html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="my"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $node_value = trim($tag->nodeValue);
    echo $node_value."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks. but a question. why xpath is better ?

Comment: xpath search your html with directly with given conditions just as we search the div with `class"my"`. no other div will get into the result. process will be done by the xpath over there. we need not to manipulate it at our page in php.

Comment: @SatishSharma thanks dear. Just a little question. If i want to crawl an external HTML page, how can i give the address of that page into your code?

Comment: by this `$html = file_get_contents($your_url);`

Answer (score 3):

You should make use of the `DOMDocument` Class

```
<?php

$html='<html>
<body>
<div class="my"> One </div>
<div class="my"> Two </div>
<div class="my"> Three </div>
<div class="other"> NO </div>
<div class="other2"> NO </div>
</body>
</html>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'my') {
        echo $tag->nodeValue; // to get the content in between of tags...
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
One Two Three
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)...

```
<?php /* crawlUrlElement.php */
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: admxxi@gmail.com
 * Date: 15/03/2017
 * Time: 15:01
 */
require("simple_html_dom.php");

function crawlUrlElement($url, $search){

    $crawlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,             // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,            // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,             // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",               // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "samplebot",      // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,             // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,              // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,              // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 5,                // stop after 5 redirects
    );

    //-- Curl Start --
    $curlObject = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curlObject,$crawlOptions);
    $webPageContent = curl_exec($curlObject);
    $errorNumber = curl_errno($curlObject);
    curl_close($curlObject);
    //-- Curl End --

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html($webPageContent);
    // Find all images
    foreach($html->find($search) as $element){
        // print_r($element);
        return (string)$element;
    }
}

// echo var_dump(crawlUrlElement('http://www.google.com','body'));
echo var_dump(crawlUrlElement('http://www.google.com','#hplogo'));

?>
```

And you will need a small change on the 'simple_html_dom.php'...

1. Rename the parameter `$url` to `$contents`
2. Comment out line 76.

   ```
   function file_get_html($contents, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
   {
       // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
       $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
       // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
       // $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Donald Duck